Having a hard time finding classical examples of eo (the verb)
I am having a hard time finding examples of the word eo (to go). For example, I searched Perseus for both it and isse in multiple plays of Plautus like Pseudolus, Menaechmi, Miles Gloriosus, and a lot of Sallust and several biographies by Cornelius Nepos, and could find not a single instance of those two words in any of them. Am doing something wrong in my search or do these authors just not use that word for some reason?

Have you tried searching for "ivit" and "ivisse"?

Try searching through PHI instead. To search for a word, place #'s around it, like #it#.
See here for the first page of the results, which, as you can see as you go through the pages, show up many times in Plautus.
Here's the link for isse, too.

Thanks very much.

@TylerDurden You can also add the author in brackets, which is helpful if you're searching for a common term in a specific author, e.g. "#it# [Pl]".
